# create a procedure with cursor as parameter

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I wrote this code and it works ok:

```
declare 
  cursor c_emp is 
  select last_name, first_name from employees;
  type c_list is table of employees.last_name%type index by binary_integer;
  type c_list2 is table of employees.first_name%type index by binary_integer;
  last_list c_list;
  first_list c_list2;
  counter integer := 0;
begin
  for i in c_emp loop
    counter := counter + 1;
    last_list(counter) := i.last_name;
    first_list(counter) := i.first_name;
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee(' || counter || '): ' || last_list(counter) || ' ' || first_list(counter));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This time I am trying to make procedure with parameters that I can insert the table name and column into the cursor. And I have tried with this :

```
create or replace procedure show_data(tab_name in varchar2, data_list in varchar2)
is 
  str varchar2(100);
  str2 varchar2(100);
  column_name varchar2(100);
begin
  str := 'select ' || data_list || ' from ' || tab_name;
  for vRec in str loop
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

It gave a error which the str is not a cursor. I am not sure that if cursor can be done in this way, but from the error it seems it can't.

Which part of my code is wrong, or because I didn't declare my cursor? But if i declare my cursor, I can't get the parameter by using dynamic sql way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should produce the same result as your original PL/SQL block. Note that the table_name can be dynamic and so can the `data_list` but you need to know the column names in the `data_list` to be able to `fetch` from the cursor and then print them.

```
create or replace procedure show_data(tab_name in varchar2
                                , data_list in varchar2)
is 
  str varchar2(100);
  str2 varchar2(100);
  column_name varchar2(100);
  TYPE cursor_ref IS REF CURSOR;
  vRec_cursor cursor_ref;
  counter integer = 0;
  last_name employee.last_name%TYPE;
  first_name employee.first_name%TYPE;
begin
  str := 'select ' || data_list || ' from ' || tab_name;
  open vRec_cursor for str;
  loop
    FETCH vRec_cursor INTO last_name, first_name;
    EXIT WHEN vRec_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee(' || counter || '): ' || last_name || ' ' || first_name;
    counter = counter + 1;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

*NOTE*: Haven't run the above code yet

Comment: Hi vmachan, Thank you so much for your reply. I have changed some of the code because there was missing semicolon. And finally I can successfully compile it!! Thank you. Now i will try to put array type in parameter so can i can have optional columns to be selected.
Once again, Thank you!!